# Getting segmentation fault when trying to print linked list data reversely using recursion

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I have created linked list of nodes. And wanted to print the data of each node reversely using **recursion** technique. I got the working as well as segfaulted code. I am trying to understand whats actually problem in segfaulted code.

Actually I tried debugging using GDB but I dont know exactly how to troubleshoot this. Any clues will be more helpful towards the clear understanding of recursion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
        char c;
        struct node *next;
} node_t;

node_t *head = NULL;

void insert_list(node_t *node)
{
    static node_t *temp = NULL;
    if (!head) {
        head = node;
        //temp = node;
    }
    else {
        temp->next = node;
    }
    temp = node;

}

void create_list(char c)
{
    node_t *temp = NULL;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if (temp) {
        temp->c = c;
        temp->next = NULL;
        insert_list(temp);
    }
    else
        return;
}

void print_list_reversely(node_t *temp)
{
    if (!temp)
        return;
    //print_list_reversely(temp->next); /* Working piece */
    temp = temp->next; /* This and next line together*/
    print_list_reversely(temp); /* Causing SEGFAULT */
    printf("data is %c\n", temp->c);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    create_list('a');   
    create_list('b');   
    create_list('c');
    print_list_reversely(head);
    return 0;
}
```

After some GDB debugging got the below info:

> A) print_list_reversely(temp->next);

```
Breakpoint 4, print_list_reversely (temp=0x0) at create.c:40
40      if (!temp)
(gdb) p temp
$5 = (node_t *) 0x0
(gdb) n
41          return;
(gdb) n
47  }
(gdb) n
print_list_reversely (temp=0x602050) at create.c:45
45      printf("data is %c\n", temp->c);
```

=======

> B) temp = temp->next; 
>   print_list_reversely(temp);

```
Breakpoint 4, print_list_reversely (temp=0x0) at create.c:40
40      if (!temp)
(gdb) p temp
$3 = (node_t *) 0x0
(gdb) n
41          return;
(gdb) n
47  }
(gdb) 
print_list_reversely (temp=0x0) at create.c:45
45      printf("data is %c\n", temp->c);
```

Comment: I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging of your code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: @KamilCuk: Shall you try run now with the updated code.

Comment: You have ***multiple*** null-pointer dereferences.

Comment: Your code has a null pointer dereference errror. a live test of your code is here: https://segfault.stensal.com/a/4D4944dmmS9BarL1   You can fix it and test it again.

Answer (score 4):

Consider you are at the last node.

```
//temp = temp->next; /* This and next line together*/
//print_list_reversely(temp); /* Causing SEGFAULT */
printf("data is %c\n", temp->c);
```

You assign `tmp` to `NULL` and you try to print it causing `NULL` pointer dereference.

---

Consider you have list as below

```
1->2->NULL
```

And your recurssion calls are

```
print_list_reversely(1)
           tmp = [2]
                 --->      print_list_reversely(2)
                           tmp = [NULL]
                                          --->      print_list_reversely(NULL)
                                                    return;
                           print(null->c) //Seg fault
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method `print_list_reversely()` is called recursively from the first element to the last, and that's the intended behaviour.

Seen how you defined your lists, the next element of the last will be `NULL`.

if you uncomment your two faulty lines (EDIT: you uncommented them now), when the `temp = temp->next;` is executed on the last element, you have null. And you dereference this pointer with `printf("data is %c\n", temp->c);`

Therefore, this code is incorrect and segfault.

You have to check that your pointer is not null before calling the function back (or dereferencing it!)

Comment: But after moving temp everytime, print_list_reversely(temp) is called which do NULL check  at the beginning itself rt.

Comment: @renga_in_stack Yes but do you do the same null-pointer check *after* the assignment `temp = temp->next`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : I am trying to understand the logical difference between the below code: print_list_reversely(temp->next);  Vs temp = temp->next; print_list_reversely(temp);

Comment: @renga_in_stack The problem isn't the recursive call, the problem is the `printf` call afterwards, where you dereference a null pointer with `temp->c`. Well, that's *one* of the null-pointer dereferences you have.

Comment: @renga_in_stack As for `print_list_reversely(temp->next);`versus `temp = temp->next; print_list_reversely(temp);`, that *alone* isn't any different.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: In GDB, I am seeing two different behaviors. In Case A once temp reaches NULL, jump to previous frame temp=0x602050 is happeninng. Why that jump is not there in Case B.

Comment: @renga_in_stack Compiler optimizations? The two short snippets you presented in the comment above are ***on their own*** semantically equivalent. What optimizations the compiler does with them is a very different matter.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Ok then is there any way to findout what kindof compiler optimization done in these 2 semantics.

Comment: @renga_in_stack Look at the generated code? Using tools such as Godbolts [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org) makes it very easy to see such differences side by side.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Great, Really useful tool.  I got this difference in CaseB  mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax  mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]

Answer (score 0):

The last pointer temp passed in the recursion is NULL, so accessing NULL must result in a segment error

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004005c1 in print_list_reversely (temp=0x0) at linked_list.c:40
40      printf("data is %c\n", temp->c);
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000004005c1 in print_list_reversely (temp=0x0) at linked_list.c:40
#1  0x00000000004005bd in print_list_reversely (temp=0x601050) at linked_list.c:39
#2  0x00000000004005bd in print_list_reversely (temp=0x601030) at linked_list.c:39
```